# GAE & lxml : cleaning HTML but not style attribute

Tags: python, css, google-app-engine, lxml

I am using Google App Engine with Python 2.7 and lxml 2.3.5
My server receives html I would like to clean but I want to keep style attributes.

```
cleaner=lxml.html.clean.Cleaner()
cleaner.clean_html(html_str)
```

But the style attributes are stripped away from the html string.
I have seen solutions for lxml 3.2 but none seem to work with me (How to preserve inline CSS style ...). Any idea?

Comment: Why are you using ancient version 2.3 of `lxml`?  Update to `3.2` and your problem might go away; if not, edit your Q and give a small reproducible example of misbehavior, and you will make it **much** easier for us to help you!

Comment: @AlexMartelli its not possible to use 3.2 on app engine, unfortunately, but if you can kick some googlers to update it -- would be really helpful.

Comment: So have you tried specifically passing `style=False` as you instantiate `Cleaner`?  It's the default in 3.2 but I don't recall what the default was in 2.3...

Answer (score 0):

We use this hack for cleaning up our HTML, as it's currently not possible to use latest lxml version on GAE (but be careful with monkey patching!):

```
import lxml.html.clean

def cleanup(s):
  if s == '':
    return ''

  safe_attrs = list(lxml.html.clean.defs.safe_attrs) + ['style', 'bgcolor']
  lxml.html.clean.defs.safe_attrs = safe_attrs
  lxml.html.clean.Cleaner.safe_attrs = lxml.html.clean.defs.safe_attrs
  cleaner = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner(
    style=False, remove_tags=['body'], safe_attrs_only=True,
    safe_attrs=safe_attrs, kill_tags=['title'])
  return cleaner.clean_html(s)
```